# Solving The Equation (Venn Diagram)

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

In a community, there are $20$ people who know at least a language(German or italian) and $30$ people who at most a language(German or italian).  The people who know no language is $3$ times of the people who know the both language.  How many people who know no language are there?

I drew up the venn diagram and given numbers for regions.

$$r(1) = \text {who knows german}$$
$$r(2) = \text {who knows italian} $$
$$r(3) = \text {who knows both} $$
$$r(4) = \text {who knows no language}$$

The equation part

$$r(1) + r (2) + r (3) = 20$$

$$r(1) + r (2) + r (4) = 30$$

$$r (4) = 3\times r (3) $$

Might I get some help?

Comment: I edited it a sec ago.

Comment: What am i missing? Also I am so confused right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is depicted below:

[image]

Here $two$, $one$, $zero$, $\color{blue}{at \ most \ one}$, $at\  least\ one$ mean that in the given region people speak that many languages.

We have that $$two+one=20,\tag 1$$ $$zero+one=30,\tag 2$$ and $$zero =3\times two.\tag 3$$

**EDIT**

Substitute $(3)$ in $(2)$. We have the following two equations now:

$$two+one=20,\tag 4$$ $$3\times two+one=30\tag 5$$

Subtract $(4)$ from $(5)$: $$2\times two=10.$$
So, $two=5$. Then, from $(1)$ $one=15.$

Finally, the solution of the equations is $two=5$, $one=15$, and $zero=15.$

**EDIT 2**

The problem with the original approach is that

$$r(1)+r(2)+r(3)\not = 20.$$

The right equation is

$$r(1)+r(2)-r(3)=20$$

because $r(1)+r(2)$ contains $r(3)$ twice. Is this enough?

---

OK, let's step further. The equation $r(1)+r(2)+r(4)=30$ is not correct either. The correct equation is $$r(1)+r(2)-2r(3)+r(4)=30$$
because, as I mentioned above the sum $r(1)+r(2)$ contains $r(3)$ twice. So, $r(1)+r(2)-2r(3)$ is the number of people who speak only one language.

Now, we have three equations:

$$r(1)+r(2)-r(3)=20,$$ $$r(1)+r(2)-2r(3)+r(4)=30,$$$$3r(3)=r(4).$$

Substituting the last equation, we get

$$r(1)+r(2)-r(3)=20,$$
$$r(1)+r(2)+r(3)=30.$$

From here $$r(1)+r(2)=25.$$

And finally, from the first equation, we get that $r(3)=5$ and then $$r(4)=3r(3)=15.$$ But we cannot calculate $r(1)$ and $r(2)$ separately.

Comment: You need to swap one and two. The approach seems true.

Comment: More lucid than mine.

Comment: @kimiTanaka: Thank you and thank you again.

Comment: Can you be more clear at solution of equation part?

Comment: @Morata: Yes, I'll edit.

Comment: Also can you do it with like $r (1)\space r (2) ...$ I might get it easily with this way.

Comment: OK: Another edit soon.

Comment: You are great! Im waiting for it.

Comment: @Morata: I did my edits.

Comment: What a great answer! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Morata: I am a big fan of Mishima and Morita. Do you know who they are?

Comment: Yes lmao why?...

Comment: Also I couldnt get the substituting part.